# GWT Compile error:

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

I created a service, async, impl for an rpc service.  However, when I go to do the gwt compile (I'm using Eclispe Indigo with the gwt 2.4 plugin) I'm getting these errors:

Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.

Scanning for additional dependencies: file:/C:/.../client/activity/CalculatorActivity.java

Computing all possible rebind results for '...Calculator.client.CalculatorService'
         Rebinding com... CalculatorService

Checking rule 
[ERROR] Errors in 'file:/...Calcuator/src/...Calculator/client/CalculatorService.java'

[ERROR] Line 17: No source code is available for type java.io.InputStream; did you forget to inherit a required module?

[ERROR] Unable to find type '...Calculator.client.CalculatorService'

[ERROR] Hint: Previous compiler errors may have made this type unavailable

[ERROR] Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly

[ERROR] Errors in 'file:/...Calculator/client/activity/CalculatorActivity.java'

[ERROR] Line 59:  Failed to resolve '...CalculatorService' via deferred binding

[ERROR] Cannot proceed due to previous errors

I'm not sure what is causing this?  I'm not getting any compile errors under Eclipse, but something isn't setup right for the RPC service apparently.

Any ideas as to what the problem is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems, you use the InputStream class somewhere in your client side code. But in client side code you are restricted to the classes mentioned in the [JRE Emulation Reference](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/webtoolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html).